# How do I access and get the property of another class?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have an application **WPF MVVM** that allows an **employee** to create **one or more projects** and each project belongs to **an employee** so my question is:
When I add an employee I also want to add a project so that **the project receives** the **ID** of the **employee** so that I can identify the relationship between the employee and the project. Here is an example:

```
Employee (Id = 1) --------> Project (id = 1)
                            Project (id = 2) 
                            Project (id = 3)

Employee (Id = 2) --------> Project (id = 4) 
                            Project (id = 5) 
                            Project (id = 6)
```

Here is my code:

Employee ViewModel:

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
{
    Employee _employee = new Employee();

    private IList<Project> _ListeProject;

    public IList<Project> ListeProject
    { get; set; }

    public void InsetEmployee(Employee Employee)
    {
        context.Employee.Add(Employee);
        context.Entry(Employee).State = EntityState.Added;
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    private void AddEmployee()
    { InsetEmployee(_employee); }
}
```

Project ViewModel:

```
public class ProjectViewModel 
{
    Project _project = new Project();
    ProjectBL _projectBL = new ProjectBL ();

    private void AddProject()
    { _projectBL.InsetProject(_project); }        
}
```

Employee.xaml:

```
<telerik:RadButton  Content="Add" Height="23" Name="btnAdd"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
    Width="120" Command="{Binding AddEmployeeCMD}"/>
<telerik:RadButton   Content="Add Project" Height="23"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
    Width="120" Click="Project"/>
```

Comment: Start by writing some code. If you can't figure it out, update the question with the appropriate code from your viewmodel and your class definitions, and folks will be able to help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on how You store it and so on. If it is stored in relational database, then easiest thing to do is creat foreing keys, this would be one to many relationship, where one Employee has multiple projects but each project have got only one owner (Employee). And then in code You have to have properties which reflect this relantionship, e.g. Project would have EmployeeId property, and Employee would have list of project ids as a property. You could also use seperate table / object to store relationship if You don't want to change Your classes.

Comment: yes i did that but my problem is when adding a new project i want that this project get the id of the employee

Comment: You need to pass id of the employee to the AddProject method, from the code You showed there is no way to do that, becuase You create project in ProjectViewModel, and Employee in EmployeeViewModel. Basically You need to somehow connect these, e.g. make AddProject public and call it from EmployeeViewModel, I don't really understand why You have one instance of Project and Employee in Your ViewModels, and why You pass it to InsertX functions. It's a reference so You will never create more then one in Your app with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a simple enough problem to solve.

```
class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}

class Project
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

var employee = new Employee { Id = 1, Projects = new List<Project>
{
    new Project { EmployeeId = 1, Name = "Foo" },
    new Project { EmployeeId = 1, Name = "Bar" }
}};
```

Comment: Please where i must put var employee = new Employee { Id = 1, Projects = new List<Project>
{
    new Project { EmployeeId = 1, Name = "Foo" },
    new Project { EmployeeId = 1, Name = "Bar" }
}};

Comment: Post some more code. It's hard to get any context from the few snippets you've posted. What is `InsetEmployee`. Also post the xaml please.